# Alternative way to communicate "Fill Rate"

Tags: meaning, terminology

I am working with customers in an app that helps them visualize where their products are in the order management process. Recently with some testing I discovered that the users were confused by the status stage titled "Fill Rate". When explored further with users a pattern emerged where I found out that the terms "fill rate" didn't mean anything to them.

I expanded on the issue with users and unfortunately didn't come up with a clear verbiage to properly communicate what this stage is. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Your users may not be the only people confused by "Fill Rate."  It appears to me to be a measure of how many of the ordered items were delivered on-time, but that doesn't seem to make sense as a status, or stage. Perhaps you could explain its meaning to us.

Comment: Sure thing. Fill rate is currently defined for us as a measure of inventory currently prepared for shipment from our warehouse.

Comment: @Cutter going from that description, does the stage "Fill Rate" mean that their product has been included in that measure of inventory prepared for shipment?

Comment: Yes @Kanga_Roo. You'd be right in that.

Comment: Maybe "Ready to Ship" or "Fulfilment Level" would be better. "Fill Rate" sounds like it is the speed at which boxes are being filled.

Comment: The noun "rate" usually refers to a speed or frequency, like "crime rate". I agree with "level" as a better term.

Comment: @JamesRandom Good suggestions. I especially like "Ready to Ship". Its a far easier term for our user base. If you'd want to add it below I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: Maybe, just maybe you should tell us what YOU mean by "fill rate".  To me it means how quickly water is going into the bathtub (or beer into the mug).  And don't put it in comments -- edit your original question!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the additional context you've provided in the comments, a better alternative would likely be "Ready for Shipment" or "Prepared for Shipment", both of which are far less ambiguous than "Fill Rate"

Answer (score 0):

From a comment under the question you say that "fill rate is currently defined for us as a measure of inventory currently prepared for shipment from our warehouse."

Based on that, I would suggest not using *fill rate* (which has the connotation of liquid or other material *filling up* something), but:

> order fulfillment rate

This has the benefit of clearly expressing the idea that it's not the specific *items* that are being filled, but the orders as a whole.

Comment: Rate would reference speed. This is more about what percentage (or actual number) of the inventory is ready to ship.